# No content is displayed after </ div> in an else if

Tags: php, html, loops, if-statement

(Translation made ​​with google, sorry.) Need to evaluate this condition which is inside a loop. if true, the `</ div>` (which was opened outside) is closed, add a `<iframe>` and replay the loop. My problem is that in the "elsif" when closed first div, it goes without displaying the following. The first "if" works perfect.

```
<?php if($adcount == 8 and $bbb == 8 and $paged == 0) { ?>
    </div>
    <div id="adds-inner" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <iframe id="my_ad" src="/ad.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
<?php } else if($adcount == 8 and $bbb == 8 and $paged > 0) { ?>
    <p> this is shown </ p> 
    </div>
    <p> Incredibly, this does not </ p> 
    <div id="adds-inner" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <iframe id="my_ad" src="/ad2.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**UPDATE**

the problem was due to a plugin (infinite scroll) misconfigured, the php code was working perfect. Thank you all for your support and sorry for the mistake.

Comment: If every single conditional starts with `</div>`, then why put `</div>` inside each of your condition blocks? Just take that `</div>` out and move it to the top, and remove the `else { ` too as it's no longer useful.

Comment: you're right, I've tried many things and cheese that mistake. I've already changed. thanks

Comment: @JorgeAdriánSolimanoInglese did my answer solve your problem? If so please give it the checkmark. If not, let me know and I will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is what you think it is. As @JoshfromQaribou said in this comment we can mode the `</div>` out of the if else statement because it will be needed regardless of the logic. But the problem seems to be your else if statement is never being reached. I can't tell without seeing the full code but if you are only getting the `</div>` and not the rest then that code is never being reached and it is going straight to the else.

Try this code:

```
  </div> <?php #<----- See how I moved this out of each below. ?> 
<?php if($adcount == 8 and $bbb == 8 and $paged == 0) { ?>
  <br />First Condition<br />
  <div id="adds-inner" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <iframe id="my_ad" src="/ad.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
<?php } else if($adcount == 8 and $bbb == 8 and $paged > 0) { ?>
  <br />Second Condition<br />
  <div id="adds-inner" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <iframe id="my_ad" src="/ad2.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <br />No conditions met.<br />
<?php } ?>
Done with conditions.
```

I bet you get "No conditions met.". It could be because `$paged` is less than 0 or one(or both) of your other variable isn't equal to 8.

**Update**

With your updated code I can see that your `else if` condition is being met. It is really weird that this only displays some of your HTML. I am not sure it will do anything for you but try this refactored code. Simplifying the code may make the problem more obvious.

```
  </div>
<?php if($adcount == 8 && $bbb == 8) { ?>
  <div id="adds-inner" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <iframe id="my_ad" src="<?php if($paged==0) echo "/ad.html" else if($paged > 0) echo "/ad2.html" ?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Just copy and past this where your code was. Don't make any changes.

Comment: thanks for answering. the code is too long to share here, just have to tell you that if you are entering the "elseif" ... I modified the code so you can see as I checked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `echo` your html instead of just having it there. I find that sometimes using html like that gives me bugs so i usually echo and wrap the html in single quotes.

Comment: To keep it simple: You are telling php to output something to the html document instead of just having it on the html document in the first place. It also breaks syntax highlighting and there is no reason to `echo` an entire document of HTML with one section of PHP.

Comment: "using html like that" does not give you bugs. The way you are suggesting leads you to make ugly php like `<?php echo '<div id="'.$divID.'">'.$divValue.'</div>' ?>`. You can make it less ugly with double quotes but you said single and less ugly is still more ugly than pretty.

Comment: i guess its each to their own

Comment: I think you will change you mind about doing it this way after spending more time in PHP (or Ruby etc.). You can do it how you prefer. I just wanted you to know it is safe (and a lot more common) to do it the normal way.